# fabric Low level connection error

Tags: python, django, fabric

I have a fabric file `fabfile.py` that runs in python 2.7 and my code looks like:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
from fabric.contrib.files import append, exists, sed

env.hosts = ["127.0.0.1"]

env.user = raw_input('Please enter user:')

def check_dependency():
    sudo("apt-get update -y")
    sudo("apt-get install git -y")
    sudo("apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev python-dev python-pip -y")
    sudo("apt-get install redis-server -y")
    sudo("apt-get install nginx -y")
```

when I run the `fabfile.py` it asks for user and I gave it `sudo` because I want to test it in my machine. When I do that i get error saying `Fatal error: Low level socket error connecting to host 127.0.0.1 on port 22: Connection refused (tried 1 time)`

Why I am getting this error ? 
Also what If I want to run this file in server? What should be the host and user ?

Thank you

Comment: Entering sudo for user is not correct, you have to use an actual username that exists on your computer. However the problem you are seeing is not because of that. It seems that your SSHD has not started.

Comment: How can I start it ??

Comment: That depends on what your operating system is.

Comment: I do believe it's /etc/init.d/sshd start